# How can I determine the physical location of a Salesforce Pod/Instance?

Tags: instance

Given a Salesforce pod/instance name such as NA3 or CS6 how can I find it's  physical location?

Comment: This question has been asked at least twice before. Can you hunt one of those and answer there? (On mobile)

Comment: @AdrianLarson I saw a couple when posting the question that were related but not really the same question. Found a good match now, so I'll close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Ah, there it is. The higher voted answer wasn't there when last I checked. May be a user who will never come back and accept the updated solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can do a DNS lookup to find what it is an alias for. E.g. for na5 via [DNS lookup](http://ping.eu/nslookup/).

> na5.salesforce.com is an alias for na5-chi.salesforce.com.
>   na5-chi.salesforce.com has address 96.43.147.57
>   na5-chi.salesforce.com has address 96.43.147.185

Note the na5-**chi**. That would be the CHI airport code - so somewhere in Chicago.

Again for cs6:

> cs6.salesforce.com is an alias for cs6-tyo.salesforce.com.
>   cs6-tyo.salesforce.com has address 182.50.78.35
>   cs6-tyo.salesforce.com has address 182.50.78.163

So TYO - Tokyo.

Interestingly enough, the location based on the [IP address alone](http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/182.50.78.35) is Singapore.

Comment: The data centre used to be in Singapore and it's moved to Japan now. I guess they are still using the old DNS servers though.

Comment: Yeah, it will be something like that. Interesting that the DNS alias gives a more accurate location.